# Error when trying to install pylivetrader with pip

Tags: python, pip

So when I'm trying to install pylivetrader using pip I get this error:

```
    Running setup.py install for bottleneck ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Devx86\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bslcwm9e\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Devx86\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bslcwm9e\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Devx86\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kiysw3cb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Include\bottleneck'
         cwd: C:\Users\Devx86\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bslcwm9e\bottleneck\
    Complete output (49 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
    copying bottleneck\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
    copying bottleneck\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\slow
    copying bottleneck/slow\move.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/slow
    copying bottleneck/slow\nonreduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/slow
    copying bottleneck/slow\nonreduce_axis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/slow
    copying bottleneck/slow\reduce.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/slow
    copying bottleneck/slow\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/slow
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\input_modifcation_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\list_input_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\move_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\nonreduce_axis_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\nonreduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\reduce_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    copying bottleneck/tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/tests
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\benchmark
    copying bottleneck/benchmark\autotimeit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/benchmark
    copying bottleneck/benchmark\bench.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/benchmark
    copying bottleneck/benchmark\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/benchmark
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src
    copying bottleneck/src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src\template
    copying bottleneck/src/template\template.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src/template
    copying bottleneck/src/template\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src/template
    package init file 'bottleneck/src/auto_pyx\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck\src\auto_pyx
    copying bottleneck/src/auto_pyx\move_setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src/auto_pyx
    copying bottleneck/src/auto_pyx\nonreduce_axis_setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src/auto_pyx
    copying bottleneck/src/auto_pyx\nonreduce_setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src/auto_pyx
    copying bottleneck/src/auto_pyx\reduce_setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck/src/auto_pyx
    copying bottleneck\LICENSE -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\bottleneck
    running build_ext
    building 'reduce' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\bottleneck
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\bottleneck\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\bottleneck\src\auto_pyx
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include -Ic:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\Include" /Tcbottleneck/src/auto_pyx/reduce.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\bottleneck/src/auto_pyx/reduce.obj
    reduce.c
    c:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Devx86\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bslcwm9e\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Devx86\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bslcwm9e\\bottleneck\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Devx86\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kiysw3cb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\devx86\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Include\bottleneck' Check the logs for full command output
```

I have my pip updated to the latest version and I'm using python 3.6 which is supported by pylivetrader. I first had a error with egg_info but I fixed that by updating pip. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: "_Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory_"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27io.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory